# how can I relation between 2 app in micro frontend with webpack module federation (angular)

Tags: angular, webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

hi there assume that we have a library and an app in angular and we want show a component from library in modal in our app
the solution is here
we install our library in our app as dependency in (package.json)
but my question is If our architecture is micro frontend
we have 2 app instead library
imagine that we want to show a component  from app1 in a modal in our app2
How can we access to component from app2?
(components are in app1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I understand it right? You want to use a component in `app 2` that is in `app 1`?

If so, then I think you're doing it wrong! If you need a component in both apps you shouldn't create it in one of your apps. You may create a shared library that holds all common things between your apps and then install that library as a package in each app individually.

#UPDATE:

Take a look [here](https://www.angulararchitects.io/aktuelles/module-federation-with-angulars-standalone-components/), it may help you find a better design.